# How do I grab all paragraphs from an article instead of just one?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Beginner here.

I've just begun learning Python and I'm learning to webscrape and I want to grab each paragraph and then write them on either a text file or a csv. Each paragraph has the same tag name so I figured a for loop would go through each tag of that name and grab the text from each one and viola!... Except it only displays the first paragraph 15+ times.. I'm assuming the reason why it does this is because it grabs the first tag like I told it to and prints that same tag for as many other tags that have the same name as it. I tried to replace .find with .find_all but I get an attribute error.. How do I grab all of the paragraphs and not just one?

Article: https://www.huffpost.com/entry/angry-squirrel-attacks-queens_n_5fee30b1c5b6ec8ae0b242d2

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
    }


url = "https://www.huffpost.com/entry/angry-squirrel-attacks-queens_n_5fee30b1c5b6ec8ae0b242d2"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

article = soup.find('article')

headline = article.header.h1.text
print(headline)

headline_Sub = article.find('div', class_="headline__subtitle").text
print(headline_Sub)

print('')

for summaries in article.find('div', class_="entry__text js-entry-text yr-entry-text"):
    p = article.find('div', class_='content-list-component yr-content-list-text text').p.text
    print(p)
```

for loop with find_all instead returns an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Denze\MyPythonScripts\Webscraping learning\Webscrape
> article.py", line 27, in 
> p = article.find_all('div', class_='content-list-component yr-content-list-text text').p.text   File
> "C:\Users\Denze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py",
> line 2173, in **getattr**
> raise AttributeError( AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'p'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a
> single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Post the error in full. Though I suspect it's because you're not treating the results of `.find_all()` it like an iterable.

Comment: Okay I've added the error message in my post, I'd be curious to know why exactly I'm getting this error..

Comment: Yeah, `.find_all()` returns a collection and you're treating it like it was a single element. In fact the error tells you exactly that in its last couple of sentences.

Comment: Just started out programming so I'm still a little confused with what all the terminology means but thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using select method to get all the paragraph elements. Take a look to this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
    }


url = "https://www.huffpost.com/entry/angry-squirrel-attacks-queens_n_5fee30b1c5b6ec8ae0b242d2"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

h1=soup.find('h1')
article = soup.select('p')


print(h1.text+'\n')
for i in article:
  print(i.text)
```

Comment: Interesting, so basically the h1 variable grabs the first h1 tag it sees using the .find method. then using the .select method on soup, it grabs the first 'p' tag it sees and then the for loop loops over every 'p' tag within the article and prints it's text? What's the difference between the .find and the .select. Couldn't I use the .find_all method to find all 'p' tags?

Comment: @JohnnySilverhand Correction: It grabs *all* the `p` tags and loops over those. Also, `.find()` and `.find_all()` uses BeautifulSoup's search while `.select()` uses a CSS style search.